# How to hide a div after click on another div

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, hide

I want to hide my div after click on a search icon, it isn't a button so I don't really know how to do it. I want to hide this text "

Simply click on the … and type the name of where you would like to visit

"  by clicking on the div class="search-icon".

```
<div id="intro"> 
            <p>Simply click on the &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-search"></i>&nbsp; and type the name of where you would like
                to visit</p>
            <div class="search-box">
                <input id="searchBox" type="text" placeholder="Search your location">
                <div class="search-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="cancel-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="search-data"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[It looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brj7Y.png)

I've tried few js code but because it isn't a button I am not sure hot it should work.

Comment: "I want to hide my div after click on a search icon". Which div you want to hide? Which search icon should listen to clicks. Please update your question so that it will be clear for readers.

Comment: Can you please include to the question the js code you have tried and what was the result? The easiest way would be to add an `id` to you `<p>` tag

Comment: You can add a click event to a div just like you would a button.

Comment: Would you like to click on the check mark beside my answer if it helped.

Comment: Yes Sunny of course, I was lookng at sth to appreciate your help, and didn't know which one should I click :D Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to give `<p>` and second search icon a clear classes, so you can select them in the dom:

```html
<div id="intro">
  <p class="text">Simply click on the &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-search"></i>&nbsp; and type the name of where you would like to visit</p>
  <div class="search-box">
    <input id="searchBox" type="text" placeholder="Search your location">
    <div class="search-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-search search-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="cancel-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="search-data"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then for the JS part first you need to select that paragraph and the second search icon:

```js
const searchIcon = document.querySelector(".search-icon");
const text = document.querySelector(".text");

searchIcon.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    text.classList.add("hide-text");
  }
});
```

and for actually hiding the text you need to add a css class:

```css
.hide-text {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to use the click event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

the best way to do his is to add an id on your element you want clickable then here's the code :

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  document.getElementById('bar').style.display = 'none'
});
```

```html
<div id="foo">Hide bar</div>
<div id="bar">Bar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Collapsible from Bootstrap for easy and Fast Solution

Comment: I don't think it would work, because the OP wants the element (`<p>`) to be hidden on click of another element (`<div class="search-box">`)

Comment: Thank you both for your time and help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding in your question.

If you want to hide any element, you can select it by its ID or class name. Here, I used the class name. Since there are two elements with the same class name, I manually selected the first one.
Here is the code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fas fa-search")[0].hidden = true
```

Comment: yes, i've noticed half of the questions didn't show. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('.search-icon').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  document.getElementById('para').style.display = 'none'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="intro"> 
            <p id="para">Simply click on the &nbsp;
 <i class="fas fa-search"></i>&nbsp; and type the name of where you would like
            to visit</p>
        <div class="search-box">
            <input id="searchBox" type="text" placeholder="Search your location">
            <div class="search-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="cancel-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="search-data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```